# Laravel n-level categories

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

***I have***
Created two tables:
1. categories

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');            
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

2. category_closure

```
Schema::create('category_closure', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('ancestor', false, true);
        $table->integer('descendant', false, true);
        $table->integer('depth', false, true);

        $table->foreign('ancestor')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('descendant')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In category table I have my categories data and relations in category_closure

```
categories                  category_closure
+----+-----------------+   +----+----------+------------+-------+  
| id | title           |   | id | ancestor | descendant | depth |  
+----+-----------------+   +----+----------+------------+-------+  
| 1  | Real Estate     |   | 1  |     1    |      1     |   0   |  
| 2  | Vehicles        |   | 2  |     2    |      2     |   0   |  
| 3  | Clothing        |   | 3  |     3    |      3     |   0   |  
| 4  | Apartments      |   | 4  |     1    |      4     |   1   |  
| 5  | Used Cars       |   | 5  |     2    |      5     |   1   |  
| 6  | Women Clothing  |   | 6  |     3    |      6     |   1   |  
| 7  | Women T-shirt   |   | 7  |     6    |      7     |   2   |
| 8  | Men's Clothing  |   | 8  |     3    |      8     |   1   |
```

Now for example category Clothing
3 - 3 returns clothing - clothing
3 - 6 returns clothing - women's clothing
3 - 8 returns clothing - men's clothing
etc.

***Question***

I can't get my head around how to define Eloquent relation in my Models to get categories with descendants.

Category Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';    
    protected $hidden = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public function nodes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoryClosure::class, 'ancestor');
    }
    public function leafs()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoryClosure::class, 'descendant');
    }    
}
```

And CategoryClosure

```
class CategoryClosure extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category_closure';
    protected $fillable = ['ancestor', 'descendant', 'depth'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'ancestor');
    }
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'descendant');
    }
}
```

How to get tree from closure table like this?

***Update***
So far what I have achieved in mysql level

```
SELECT * FROM categories JOIN trees ON (categories.id = trees.descendant) WHERE trees.ancestor = 1;
```

this gives me this output if category 1 is selected

```
    +----+-------------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----+----------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | id | title       | slug        | position | real_depth | deleted_at | created_at          | updated_at          | id | ancestor | descendant | depth | created_at          | updated_at          |
    +----+-------------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----+----------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |  1 | Real Estate | real_estate |        0 |          0 | NULL       | 2016-04-04 15:00:00 | 2016-04-04 15:00:00 |  1 |        1 |          1 |     0 | 2016-04-04 20:00:00 | 2016-04-04 20:00:00 |
    |  4 | Apartments  | apartments  |        0 |          1 | NULL       | 2016-04-04 15:00:00 | 2016-04-04 15:00:00 |  2 |        1 |          4 |     1 | 2016-04-04 20:00:00 | 2016-04-04 20:00:00 |
    |  5 | Houses      | houses      |        1 |          1 | NULL       | 2016-04-04 15:00:00 | 2016-04-04 15:00:00 |  3 |        1 |          5 |     1 | 2016-04-04 20:00:00 | 2016-04-04 20:00:00 |
    +----+-------------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----+----------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So I know it's working, now how to transfer this to view...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this package: https://packagist.org/packages/franzose/closure-table so you won't need to reinvent the wheel.
It provides two methods to get the whole tree:

```
$tree = Category::getTree();
```

or

```
$treeByCondition = Category::getTreeWhere('position', '>=', 1);
```

Comment: Hi @vjandrea I'm using laravel 5.1.32, after installing franzose 4.1.* I get errors like Illuminate\Support\Composer does not exist, I cant reach php artisan in command line after installation of this package. Anyways,  this question is based on SQL Antipaterns written by Bill Karwin, And in his book he suggest to use closure table for tree models. I thought this would be easy - take categories, set relations in category_closure, get results. And to retreive results he uses this code , `SELECT c.* FROM Categories AS c JOIN c.category_closure AS t ON c.id = t.descendant WHERE t.ancestor = 4`

Comment: Which procedure did you use to install closure-table? Probably a "composer dump-autoload" will fix the issues.

Comment: I tried via copy paste "franzose/closure-table": "4.*" to composer.json, then composer update, and added provider in app/config file, then composer dumpautoload -o, after all this done php artisan stops working `[ReflectionException] Class Illuminate\Support\Composer does not exist`. tried through composer require command in gitbash also, same outcome.  So after some search I found solution to fix this, in `vendor\franzose\ClosureTable\scr\Franzose\ClosureTable\Console\MakeCommand.php` changed line 6 from `use Illuminate\Support\Composer` to `use Illuminate\Foundation\Composer`

Comment: You're loading the wrong version, you should use
"franzose/closure-table": "dev-L5.1"
That's the version compatible with Laravel 5.1

Comment: Oh, thanks vjandrea, thought that 4.* version can handle laravel 5.1